# Find an element using xpath

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

Today I've met this problem:
I have some html code:

```
<div class="Main">
    <div>
        <div class="display">First:</div>
        <div class="price">$0.01</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="display">Second:</div>
        <div class="price">$0.02</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="display">Third:</div>
        <div class="price">$0.03</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to find second element, for example. What should i do? I'm using Java and Selenium and this way isn't working:

```
chromeDriver.findElement(By.className("Main"))
        .findElement(By.xpath(".//*[starts-with(@class, 'price')][2]")).getText()
```

I know about findElements-method, but i want through xpath.

Comment: Try with the following xpath expression `(//div/div[@class="price"])[2]`

Comment: Wow, so faster! Thx, what does it mean parentheses in xpath exps?

Comment: As @Ivan said, the parentheses are there to use the index accessor and then select the second element with `[2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your XPath expression there are a couple of problems:

- You need to accommodate for the container `<div>` that contains the `<div class="display"></div>` and `<div class="price"></div>` elements.
- You need to wrap your selector in `()` if you want to retrieve an element based on its index.
- You can use a single XPath expression instead of calling `findElement` twice.

Here is the expression I would use. Notice that it:

- Looks for the `<div class="Main">` element
- Accommodates the container `<div>`
- Retrieves the `text()` using XPath
- Wraps the selector in `()` so we can use the index accessor

`(//*[@class='Main']/*/*[starts-with(@class, 'price')])[2]/text()`

Answer (score 1):

Using the [1] or [2] in the xpath is **NOT** a good approach...because when the structure of the page changes your locator will not point it to the same Web element.

Better solution of the problem would be **using the text** **between the tags**.
If the text between the tag is the unique one u can directly use the text content of them in your xpath and have an access to the second element.

xpath = "//div[conatins(text(),'$0.02')]" ;

This would help you.